# Bookdown Document Not Rendering Outputs Correctly

Tags: r, r-markdown, github-actions, bookdown, github-actions-runners

I have a bookdown document that renders fine on my local machine, but when I have it run as an automated process using GitHub Actions the outputs from the individual code chunks show up all jumbled up:
[image: badly formatted output]

This is the GitHub repository for the book: https://github.com/ries9112/cryptocurrencyresearch-org

And here are where the automated runs through GitHub Actions are running: https://github.com/ries9112/cryptocurrencyresearch-org/actions

In order to help troubleshoot the problem, I created a separate repository as a much more barebones example, and I am running into the exact same issue. Here is the repository for the simpler example: https://github.com/ries9112/bookdown-test

I deployed the results from that simpler test and you can find them here: https://brave-leakey-37b898.netlify.app/intro.html#here-adding-new-test
[image]

The documents format totally fine locally, so looks like there may be something else that I need to install, but I am currently installing pandoc and tinytex, and I can't figure out what else may be missing. Here is the YAML file that defines the GitHub Action:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macOS-10.15
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v1
      - name: Install pandoc and pandoc citeproc
        run: |
          brew install pandoc
          brew install pandoc-citeproc
      - name: Install Packages
        run: |-
          Rscript -e "install.packages(c('pins','bookdown','tidyverse','DT'))"
      - name: Refresh book
        run: |-
          Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'bookdown::gitbook')"
```

Any thoughts on any anything that may be missing in those installation steps to get this to render correctly? I have tried on Ubuntu and Windows as well and ran into the same problems.

I also tried these steps for pandoc and tinytex install and ran into the same exact problem:

```
      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v1
      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-tinytex@v1
```

Would really appreciate any thoughts on how to fix this issue!

[Also posted to RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/bookdown-document-not-rendering-outputs-correctly/87831) and will update both with the answer if one is found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to deactivate coloring enabled by the **crayon** package, which is used by the tidyverse.

By default, it is activated on Github Action when you are using `setup-r`
https://github.com/r-lib/actions/blob/9598b8eeb6d88de7d76d580d84443542bbfdffce/setup-r/action.yml#L14-L16

So you need to change it to FALSE

```yaml
      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v1
        with:
          crayon.enabled: 'FALSE'
```

in you actions yaml file.

You can also deactivate it as an option in your bookdown project

```r
options(crayon.enabled = FALSE)
```

You have to do that on Github Action because crayon is not disable automatically when used in GHA. Don't know why

Comment: THANK YOU! Could you adjust the answer to be crayon.enabled: 'FALSE' ? Looks like it needs the extra quotes, but worked perfect immediately afterwards! Thansk so much!